# register component vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im using [spatie/vue-table-component](https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component) in the documentation i followed how to register the component via:

```
import TableComponent from 'vue-table-component';
Vue.use(TableComponent);
```

and i use it as

```
<table-component :data="fetchData">
    <table-column show="firstName" label="First name"></table-column>
</table-component>
```

this is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "axios": "^0.18.0",
   "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
   "vue": "^2.5.2",
   "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
   "vue-table-component": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
},
```

However i get the error `Unknown custom element: <table-component> - did you register the component correctly?` how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the documentation is valid for version 1.x, not for 2.x.

You can downgrade to previous version:

```
$ npm install --save vue-table-component@^1
```

(last version published in npm is [1.9.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-table-component/v/1.9.1))

See also https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component/issues/166

It does not seem like the version 2 (still in alpha) is easily usable for now.